# JS split() Regex with Three Matches to a single Results Array

Tags: javascript, regex, split, capture-group

I'm trying to split a string of the type below in JS with split().

```
let shape = "Cube - Level 2: three-dimensional";
```

My desired end-state is something like:

```
0: "Cube"
1: "Level 2"
2: "three-dimensional"
```

I can individually capture words preceding the `\s-\sLevel` pattern with positive lookahead:

```
(.+)(?=\s-\sLevel\s)
```

and the `Level\s[0-9]` pattern with a simple capture group:

```
(Level\s[0-9])
```

as well as the arbitrary characters after `Level:\s`:

```
(?<=[0-9]:\s).*
```

but I'm trying to figure out how to capture all three with JS split(). Is there a way to capture them such that `split[0] = "Cube"`, `split[1] = "Level 2"`, etc?

Comment: Is there a reason you're insisting on using `String.split()` here?

Comment: I ask because this is straightforward: `/^(\S+) - (Level \d+): (.*)$/.exec("Cube - Level 2: three-dimensional").slice(1)`

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of .slice()! However, it does look like it still can't handle cases where a hyphen with spaces may appear as part of a shape, e.g. "tetra - hedron".

Comment: okay, then: `/^(.*?) - (Level (?:.*?)): (.*)$/.exec("Tetra - hedron - whatever - you - like - Level 867-5309: three-dimensional").slice(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want a solution that uses `String.split()` then my answer is wrong, but if you're looking for a general answer to the question of how to match the string, then I propose:

```
/^(.*?) - (Level (?:.*?)): (.*)$/.exec(str).slice(1)
```

So, for example:

```js
let str = "Tetra - hedron - whatever - you - like - Level 867-5309: three-dimensional"

console.log(/^(.*?) - (Level (?:.*?)): (.*)$/.exec(str).slice(1))
```

```
[ 'Tetra - hedron - whatever - you - like',
  'Level 867-5309',
  'three-dimensional' ]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could alternate between a dash (surrounded by spaces) and a colon followed by a space:

```js
let shape = "Cube - Level 2: three-dimensional";
console.log(
  shape.split(/ - |: /)
);
```

If you always want to split the string into those three groups and no more, then you can *capture* the `Level` part in a capturing group:

```js
let shape = "Cube - Level 2: three-dimensional";
console.log(
  shape.split(/ - (Level \d+): /)
);
```

Comment: Thanks - do you think it's possible to restrict to dash followed by "Level" (so I would still capture 'quadri - lateral' for example) and only colon after "Level", in case there's a colon somewhere in the "three-dimensional" string?

Comment: If you only want those three groups, then rather than alternating, capture the `Level` part in a capturing group, see edit

Answer (score 1):

Create a character class with the characters , `:`, `-` and then split on 2 or 3 of those characters in row:

```js
let shape = "Cube - Level 2: three-dimensional";
console.log(shape.split(/[ \-:]{2,3}/));
```